# C# Web API loop posts one value only

Tags: c#, json, api, foreach

I read my rows from SQL into and object and then would like to post them using the code below to the web api. One row is posted, however the other 99 rows are not. Is there something missing in my code for the for each loop?

Code Below …

```
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        List<ProductSQL> myObjectList = new List<ProductSQL>();
                        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ProductSQL myObject = new ProductSQL();
                                myObject.sku = reader["sku"].ToString();
                                myObject.title = reader["title"].ToString();
                                myObject.description = reader["description"].ToString();
                                myObjectList.Add(myObject);
                            }
                        }
                        var JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjectList);
                        Console.WriteLine(myObjectList);
                        Console.WriteLine(JsonResult);



                /* Program Initialization Now need to see why multiple articles are not*/

                Console.WriteLine("Post Articles To API");
                HttpResponseMessage response2;
                Product NewProduct = new Product();
                foreach (ProductSQL product in myObjectList.ToList())
                {

                    NewProduct.sku = product.sku;
                    NewProduct.title = product.title;
                    NewProduct.description = product.description;
                }


                /* Mapping that needs to be autmated between models , Product.cs and ProductSQL.cs */

                response2 = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("sites/1/products.json",NewProduct);
                if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)

               {

                    Uri Product = response2.Headers.Location;
                    Console.WriteLine(response2);

                      }
```

Comment: You are issuing the post request outside of the `foreach` loop that's why the `PostAsJsonAsync` is only run once for the first product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You post only one product because `PostAsJsonAsync` is executed outside the foreach block!
Putting the code inside foreach block should solve your problem.

```
foreach (ProductSQL product in myObjectList)
{
    Product newProduct = new Product {
       sku = product.sku,
       title = product.title,
       description = product.description,
    }

    /* Mapping that needs to be autmated between models , Product.cs and ProductSQL.cs */    
    response2 = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("sites/1/products.json", product);
    if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Uri productUri = response2.Headers.Location;
        Console.WriteLine(response2);
    }      
}
```

---

**OTHER THINGS**:

1. *myObjectList* is already a List, so you don't need the `.ToList()`
2. What is the use of `var JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjectList);`?
3. Little thing about naming convention: `NewProduct` would be better if named `newProduct`

Comment: new at this Marco, thanks for the tips I will dig into this, big thanks for the help above with the Loop, awesome to see the results :).